# Increase the resolution of a geometry shape

Tags: c++, geometry

The task is to increase the resolution of a geometry shape like this:

[image: before]

So that the shape becomes this by adding data points:

[image: after]

The shape is define by data points which has x and y coordinates and a index. The index represent the order to connect them.
What type of algorithm should I use to achieve this?

Comment: btw the operation is called `resampling`  ...

Comment: Could you say **why** you want to do this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use linear interpolation between segment ends.

It is not clear yet - how many new points you want to insert in every segment. Does it depend on segment length or other reasons? Seems your picture shows mixed approach: `n` is at least `nmin`, part length is at most `lmax` like this

```
n = max(nmin, int(seglength / lmax)) ;
```

For `XStart, XEnd` referring to starting and ending coordinates of segment, we insert `n-1` points, dividing segment into `n` equal parts:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
   X[i] = XStart + (XEnd - XStart) * i / n;
   Y[i] = YStart + (YEnd - YStart) * i / n;
}
```